# How MDM install application on device without user interaction?

Tags: android, mdm, android-install-apk

I am working on one assignment, I need to implement silent apk installation on android phone.I checked many posts and find out that it is possible to install apk only if hone is rooted. But MDM(Mobile Device Management) tools are capable to install apk without user interaction and remotely.Can any body explain me how MDM are capable to do so?

Answer (score 1):

On Android, the MDM companies such as AirWatch must have an os-level app signature for their service app.  For example, for Samsung there is this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.airwatch.admin.samsung&hl=en

Once that service is installed, the OS allows AirWatch to do silent installs because the service is trusted as if it were part of the operating system.

Comment: Does the app in question only apply to Samsung's KNOX technology? At a basic level, I'm just trying to determine if there's an Android implementation of silent MDM installs that doesn't require Vendor specific tech (e.g. Samsung KNOX) or rooting the device (which one of the answers appears to suggest by running arbitrary commands on a remote device)